# iPhone UIScrollView, calling the pan and pinch gesture selectors programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

My needs are to override the UIScrollView pan and pinch gestures with a simple condition, so they would work only if a certain condition is true.

Overriding the default gesture was ok, disabling them and  calling my own gesture which prior logic was ok. But in case the condition is true I want to call the default selectors of the pan and pinch to obtain the normal slick scrollview behavior with bouncing and insets and such...

So how can I call the default gesture selectors programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into subclassing UIScrollView and override the following methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If the condition is true, you call the corresponding method on super.
To always enable scrolling you can check if the touches set contains exactly one object.